# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<init>(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duratio

Tags: appium-android

I m getting below error message when i try to launch the app in rela device, please help if any one face and solved already.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this to my pom.xml file fixed it for me

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm guessing a new version got released that created this error, setting the version to this one should work.

Let me know if this works for u too

Comment: The above issue resolved now after adding mentioned dependency , but now i m getting different error as mentioned below.                                                                                                   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Comment: Might be a dumb question but did you check if your appium server is running? @Vikasbijanalli

Comment: @TAFEED, Please help with the above error

Comment: It says either your URL is incorrect or your appium server is not running. @Vikasbijanalli

Comment: [Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.1.3
[Appium] Attempting to load driver uiautomator2...

[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://0.0.0.0:4723
[Appium] You can provide the following URLs in your client code to connect to this server:
[Appium]        http://192.168.0.100:4723/
[Appium]        http://127.0.0.1:4723/ (only accessible from the same host)
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - uiautomator2@2.29.10 (automationName 'UiAutomator2')

Comment: Appium 2 is up and running, but still getting error

Comment: This worked for me now , Thanks a lot @TAEFED

Comment: I suddenly started experiencing the same issue as well even though I have not changed anything in my project. Adding the above dependency fixed it but does anyone know what suddenly caused this?

Comment: Like I said in my original post, I assumed a new version of the selenium remote driver got released,and as you can now see on the maven repository, https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver
a new version got released which caused this error. I think its best to always specify versions of dependencies to avoid new versions from automatically being used and causing unspecified behaviour @cdub always good to check the compatibility matrix of the java client as well https://github.com/appium/java-client#compatibility-matrix

Answer (score 5):

Using the latest dependency of appium java-client fixed the issue.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>8.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I actually like this answer better. No need to add additional dependencies

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me also, thanks a lot TAEFED.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```